# Extending DataGrid/Changing DataGrid header

Tags: .net, wpf, wpf-controls, custom-controls

Is there any way how to override `DataGrid`s header line ? Or at least its behaviour ? I'm trying to implement Outlook-like grouping of the table. That is allow user to drag column header out of the table to the dedicated area to sort by that column (for example `XamDataGrid` has that feature, you can see how it works [here](http://dl.infragistics.com/marketing/NetAdvantage/WPF/Videos/introducingxamDataGrid.wmv)).

I cannot use any commercial solutions.

I will be thankfull for any experiences, ideas, code, notes or tutorials.

EDIT: According to some posts I was able to find, I should replace `DataGridColumnsHeaderPresenter` in the `DataGrid` to be able to do what I desire. I have never done anything like that, I have no idea where to start. OK I write my own `DataGridColumnsHeaderPresenter` that will be composed of original `DataGridColumnsHeaderPresenter` and some other components and what then? How do I get my `DataGrid` to use the new `DataGridColumnsHeaderPresenter` instead of default one ? Please provide code if possible.

Comment: http://www.pochet.net/blog/2010/08/25/drag-and-drop-grouping-in-datagrid/

check out this link to its for silverlight and for grouping but it still may help you out  :)

Comment: That is extrely helpfull! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in your resources change the part surrounded by ** to:

```
**<whatever xmlns:MyDataGridColumnHeadersPresenter x:Name="PART_ColumnHeadersPresenter" 
                                        Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Column}, 
                                        Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>**


    <Style x:Key="DataGridStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF688CAF"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="RowDetailsVisibilityMode" Value="VisibleWhenSelected"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="Both"/>
        <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="DG_ScrollViewer" Focusable="false">
                            <ScrollViewer.Template>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Button Command="{x:Static DataGrid.SelectAllCommand}" Focusable="false" Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=DataGridSelectAllButtonStyle, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type DataGrid}}}" Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.All}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" Width="{Binding CellsPanelHorizontalOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                                        <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        **<DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter x:Name="PART_ColumnHeadersPresenter" 
                                            Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Column}, 
                                            Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>**
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"    Grid.Row = "1" Grid.Column="1"   ><Button Height="100">test</Button>

                                            <Button Height="100">test</Button>
                                            <Button Height="100">test</Button>
                                            <Button Height="100">test</Button>

                                        </StackPanel>                                   

                                        </Grid><ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter" CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1"/>
                                        <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar" Grid.Column="2" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"/>
                                        <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2">
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding NonFrozenColumnsViewportHorizontalOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar" Grid.Column="1" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}" Orientation="Horizontal" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Grid>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </ScrollViewer.Template>
                            <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Declare your grid in xaml like this:

```
<DataGrid Margin="30,30,36,23" Grid.Row="1" Style="{DynamicResource DataGridStyle1}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="fiorst"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="semd"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Notice the stack panel with the buttons you can put whatever you want over there.
Hope this helps

If you want to change the DataGridColumnsHeaderPresenter I would do it like this.

```
[TemplatePart(Name = "PART_ItemsHolder", Type = typeof(Panel))]
public class MyDataGridColumnsHeaderPresenter:DataGridColumnsHeaderPresenter
{
   private Panel _itemsHolder = null;

   public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            base.OnApplyTemplate();
            _itemsHolder = GetTemplateChild("PART_ItemsHolder") as Panel;
        }

   //for whatever other functionality you need for the sorting you can use the _itemsHolder variable
}
```

This is the default template for the presenter:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter}">   
  <Grid>  
       <DataGridColumnHeader IsHitTestVisible="False"        
          Name="PART_FillerColumnHeader"/> 
       <ItemsPresenter />  
  </Grid> 
</ControlTemplate>
```

I would change it to something like this:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MyDataGridColumnHeadersPresenter}">   
  <Grid>  
       <Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <RowDefinition Height = "Auto" />  
     <RowDefinition Height = "Auto" />
       </Grid.RowDefinitions>  
       <DataGridColumnHeader IsHitTestVisible="False"        
          Name="PART_FillerColumnHeader"/> 
       <ItemsPresenter Grid.Row="0" />  
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" x:Name="PART_ItemsHolder />
  </Grid> 
</ControlTemplate>
```

Here is the style for the default DataGrid

```
<Style x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=DataGridSelectAllButtonStyle, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type DataGrid}}" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="Border" Fill="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"/>
                    <Polygon x:Name="Arrow" Fill="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="8,8,3,3" Opacity="0.15" Points="0,10 10,10 10,0" Stretch="Uniform" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="Border" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Border" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Arrow" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="DataGridStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF688CAF"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="RowDetailsVisibilityMode" Value="VisibleWhenSelected"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="Both"/>
    <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="DG_ScrollViewer" Focusable="false">
                        <ScrollViewer.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Button Command="{x:Static DataGrid.SelectAllCommand}" Focusable="false" Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=DataGridSelectAllButtonStyle, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type DataGrid}}}" Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.All}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" Width="{Binding CellsPanelHorizontalOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                                    <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter x:Name="PART_ColumnHeadersPresenter" 
                                        Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Column}, 
                                        Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"    Grid.Row = "1" Grid.Column="1"   ><Button Height="100">test</Button>

                                        <Button Height="100">test</Button>
                                        <Button Height="100">test</Button>
                                        <Button Height="100">test</Button>

                                    </StackPanel>                                   

                                    </Grid><ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter" CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1"/>
                                    <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar" Grid.Column="2" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"/>
                                    <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding NonFrozenColumnsViewportHorizontalOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar" Grid.Column="1" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}" Orientation="Horizontal" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </ScrollViewer.Template>
                        <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: This changes visual layout but it does not add functionality. Most likely I will need to use custom `DataGridColumnsHeaderPresenter` that adds new functions. How do I replace the original one ?

Comment: I dont think you need to change DataGridColumnsHeaderPresenter it inherits from itemscontrol that generates the column headers and I am not sure it is the logical place to add this panel.  If you do want to go that route though I would create a new class inheriting from it and adding a template part for the panel.  Ill add some code for this to my answer.  A better idea may be to actually extend the DataGrid control itself.

Comment: @Wegged +1 for your edit. actually I'll extend `DataGrid` but I have to replace `DataGridColumnsHeaderPresenter` for sure... That si because I want to override default drag&drop functionality of `DataGridColumnsHeaderPresenter` so that the user will be able to drag column headers to the area above where he can drop it to group by that column.

Comment: @Wegged yes I think your answer si a complex answer to my question even if it does not solve all my problems. You did not state how do I get my DataGrid to use new `MyDataGridColumnHeadersPresenter` but I already know that - I extend `DataGrid` and override metadata - if it si not correct then please correct me (some code to your answer). Anyway I guess I own you that bounty. So it is yours unless somebody quickly provide better answer :)

Comment: @Wegged: well, I do not know how to get `DataGrid` use `MyDataGridColumnHeadersPresenter` so please provide this information so I can avard you the bounty (you get half of it anyway but 50 is better then 25 right ?)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can redo the control template. [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vinsibal/archive/2008/08/14/wpf-datagrid-dissecting-the-visual-layout.aspx) is a post on the visual layout of the Datagrid. The post is a little old, but I find it useful (i have a copy posted on the wall above my desk)

Comment: Well, the post is good but it does not give me an example code and I have no idea where to start. The most complicated control I have ever templated was Button... Could you pls provide an example code ? Lets say I want to have a label saying `Hello world` between column headers and rows of the `DataGrid`. Thank you in advance :)